# Can we create more then 2 riak cluster

Tags: riak, clustered-index

Can we setup Riak Cluster with only 2 nodes like this

```
node01
node02
```

or we add more cluster or less then 2 cluster if we can then please let me how we can achieve that .

Answer (score 0):

It will depends if you are running your cluster under docker or not.

## If you are under docker

You can in this case start a new riak node with the command
`docker run -d -P -e COORDINATOR_NODE=172.17.0.3 --label cluster.name=<your main node name> basho/riak-kv`

For more explaination about this line you can go on the basho post: [Running Riak in Docker](http://basho.com/posts/technical/running-riak-in-docker/)

## If you are not under a docker container

As I didn't experimented this case personally I will only link the documentation to run a new node on a riak server: [Running a Cluster](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.3/using/running-a-cluster/)

Hope I understood the question correctly